How to Implement Soft Deletes with Laravel Activity Log?
I'm using the Spatie Laravel Activitylog package, and I want to log soft delete actions performed on my models. However, I'm having trouble getting the logs to correctly capture the deletion events. What is the best way to set this up in Laravel?
I tried configuring the Spatie Laravel Activitylog to log soft delete events by using model observers and adding the Loggable trait to my models. I expected the soft delete actions to be captured in the activity log. However, the log entries are not recording the delete actions as expected.

 $designationType = Designation::find($designationId);
            if ($designationType) {
                $designationType->delete();

Here, soft delete will get logged perfectly as the find is directly calling the eloquent orm.
Observation::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail()->delete();

Here I have to use firstOrFail if there is where clause otherwise the deletion isn't logged.

I'm having the same problem, I was thinking to use tapActivity()
like this:
' public function tapActivity(Activity $activity, string $eventName): void
{
    if ($this->deleted_at !== null) {
        $activity->description = "Order product has been deleted";
    }       
}'

this works in my case, and dont forget to remove ->dontSubmitEmptyLogs() if you are using it. And if you are trying to get the activities for a model true his dependencies, dont forget to get them withTrashed(), otherwise you will wonder why you have the logs, but can't render them (don't ask me how I know) :D
Hope that this helps you!
